Deriving Formulas for the Gaussian Process
I wrote the equations for a Gaussian Process:
$$f(x) \sim GP(m(x), k(x, x'))$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} f(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_m) \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{bmatrix} m(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ m(x_m) \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k(x_1, x_1) & \cdots & k(x_1, x_m) \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ k(x_m, x_1) & \cdots & k(x_m, x_m) \end{bmatrix}\right)$$
$$
p(y | X, \theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n |\Sigma|}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} (y - m(X))^T \Sigma^{-1} (y - m(X))\right)
$$
Given some new points $x_*$, I am trying to derive the equations for the distribution for the mean and variance of the new points:
$$[f(X), f(x_*)] \sim N\left([m(X), m(x_*)], \begin{bmatrix} K(X, X) + \sigma^2I & K(X, x_*) \\ K(x_*, X) & K(x_*, x_*) \end{bmatrix}\right)$$
$$m_{post}(x_*) = m(x_*) + K(x_*, X)[K(X, X) + \sigma^2I]^{-1}(y - m(X))$$
$$k_{post}(x_*, x'_*) = K(x_*, x'_*) - K(x_*, X)[K(X, X) + \sigma^2I]^{-1}K(X, x'_*)$$
How do we get these formulas?
Here is my logic.
Using the properties of a Multivariate Gaussian Distribution:
$$p(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2} |\Sigma|^{1/2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} (x - \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu)\right)$$
Suppose $X$ is a set of random variables that are jointly normal. If we partition $x = [x_a, x_b]$ and the mean $\mu = [\mu_a, \mu_b]$ and the covariance $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{aa} & \Sigma_{ab} \\ \Sigma_{ba} & \Sigma_{bb} \end{bmatrix}$, then the conditional of $x_a$ given $x_b$ is also Gaussian:
$$x_a | x_b \sim N(\mu_{a|b}, \Sigma_{a|b})$$
$$\mu_{a|b} = \mu_a + \Sigma_{ab} \Sigma_{bb}^{-1} (x_b - \mu_b)$$
$$\Sigma_{a|b} = \Sigma_{aa} - \Sigma_{ab} \Sigma_{bb}^{-1} \Sigma_{ba}$$
Now, we treat $a$ like the new data and $b$ like the old data, and make the following substitutions:
$$a = f(x_*)$$
$$b = f(X)$$
$$\mu_a = m(x_*)$$
$$\mu_b  = m(X)$$
$$\Sigma_{aa} = K(x_*, x_*)$$
$$\Sigma_{ab} = K(x_*, X)$$
$$\Sigma_{ba} = K(X, x_*)$$
$$\Sigma_{bb} = K(X, X) + \sigma^2I$$.
If we replace these into $\mu_{a|b}$ and $\Sigma_{a|b}$, I think we might be able to get something close to $m_{post}(x_*)$ and $k_{post}(x_*, x'_*)$?
Is this the correct logic for the derivations?

You have learnt in class that if
$$(X,Y)\sim N(m_X,m_Y; 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}A &B^T\\ B &C\end{array}\right])$$ then
$$X|Y\sim N(m_X+B^TC^{-1}(Y-m_Y); A-B^TC).$$ This formula applies mechanichally to  your problem.
